# Creating nested XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to create a nested XML structure from a flat XML using XSLT. Could you please help me on this?

Input: Elements could be till n'th level

```
<tm>
    <w001></w001>
    <w002></w002>
    <w003></w003>
    <w003></w003>
    <w002></w002>
    <w003></w003>
    <w002></w002>
    <w003></w003>
</tm>
```

The output should be:

```
<tm>
  <w001>
    <w002>
        <w003></w003>
        <w003></w003>
    </w002>
    <w002>
        <w003></w003>
    </w002>
    <w002>
        <w003></w003>
    </w002>
  </w001>
</tm>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I am fine with any version however currently using 2.0

Comment: See a very similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40866825/3016153 Your case is simpler, since you don't have leaf nodes attached at every level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Come to think of it, this could be done relatively simply by:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="children" match="*">
    <xsl:variable name="level" select="number(substring-after(name(), 'w'))" />
    <xsl:variable name="parent-name" select="format-number($level - 1, 'w000')" />
    <xsl:variable name="parent" select="preceding-sibling::*[name()=$parent-name][1]" />
    <xsl:value-of select="generate-id($parent)"/>
</xsl:key>

<xsl:template match="/tm">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="w001"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('children', generate-id())"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this assumes that no levels are skipped.

---

### Added:

> Actually there could be possibility that the levels skip.

I haven't tested this very thoroughly (having no real example of this scenario), but I think it would work if you replace the above key definition:

```
<xsl:key name="children" match="*">
    <xsl:variable name="level" select="number(substring-after(name(), 'w'))" />
    <xsl:variable name="parent-name" select="format-number($level - 1, 'w000')" />
    <xsl:variable name="parent" select="preceding-sibling::*[name()=$parent-name][1]" />
    <xsl:value-of select="generate-id($parent)"/>
</xsl:key>
```

with:

```
<xsl:key name="children" match="*" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[name() lt name(current())][1])" />
```

Comment: Yes, this works fine if no levels are skipped. Thank you so much for your help! However do you have any suggestions if levels are skipped? Actually there could be possibility that the levels skip.

Comment: @Jeet See the addition to my answer.

Comment: You are genius! Thank you so much. It works fine with my current test cases. I have been working in xslt from long time however always try to ignore use of keys however this is very useful. Now I am going to learn use of keys thoroughly. Thank you again!

Comment: @Jeet Keys are one of the most powerful tools of the XSLT language.